# a holomorphic extension of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:D(2+2i,4)\to \mathbb{C}$ with $f^{(n)}(1+i)=\frac{1}{n!}, \ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}_0$. Then $f$ extended holomorphicly on every disk $D(2+2i, 2(k+2)),\ k\in\mathbb{N}.$ My work:
By using the Identity theorem I got $f(z)$ which is holomorphic everywhere (I guess) on $\mathbb{C}$. So, $f$ extended holomorphically on every disk $D(2+2i, 2(k+2)),\ k\in\mathbb{N}.$
Is it correct? However, I don't know by hypothesis if $f$ is holomorphic anywhere else on complex plane, except point $1+i$. Does it affect that?

Comment: You define $f$ in terms of a single (which?) $n$,  when it shall have some property for every $n$?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identity Theorem implies that
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(z-1-i)^n}{(n!)^2},
$$
and $f$ is entire analytic.